# Listview item Tooltip Binding on a viewmodel variable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

`SelectableItemClass` has a string named `SI_itemName` and a bool named `SI_selected`.

ViewModel:

```
private String _testBind;
public String testBind
{
    get
    {
       return _testBind;
    }
    set
    {
        _testBind = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("testBind");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<SelectableItemClass> _SList;
public ObservableCollection<SelectableItemClass> SList
{
    get { return _SList; }
    set
    {
        _SList= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SList");
    }
}

private SelectableItemClass _SelectedSItem;
public SelectableItemClass SelectedSItem
{
    get { return _SelectedSItem; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedSItem = value;
        testBind = "TESTTTTTTT";
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSItem");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SList}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Margin="4,4,0,0" MinWidth="188" Height="200">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>
                    <Label Content="{Binding testBind}" />
                </ToolTip>                                
            </StackPanel.ToolTip>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Name="aaaa" Content="{Binding SI_itemName}" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding SI_selected}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The problem is that I'm not able to get the value of `testBind` inside the `ToolTip` in the View. 
When an element is selected the set function of `testBind` inside the viewmodel is called but an empty string is viewed on the `ToolTip`.

I've also tried with 
`RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}` on the `ToolTip` label but it doesn't work. Is it a problem with ~DataContext`or`ItemTemplate`?

**Edit:**

Tooltip and Label have the same relativesource, for the label it works, for the tooltip it doesn't

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.testBind}" />
    </StackPanel.ToolTip>
    <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.testBind}" />
    <CheckBox Name="aaaa" Content="{Binding SI_itemName}" IsChecked="{Binding SI_selected}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the link in the comment above [WPF Binding to Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083969/wpf-binding-to-tooltip/4084121) it's possible to create also a bindable object for tag property in the stackpanel.

using this tag with dot notation in order to bind different element in the tooltip to relative property in the object.

```
public class PreviewItemClass : ObservableObject
{
    private string _descr1;
    public string descr1
    {
        get
        {
            return _descr1;
        }
        set
        {
            _descr1= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("descr1");
        }
    }
    private string _descr2;
    public string descr2
    {
        get { return _descr2; }
        set
        {
            _descr = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("descr2");
        }
    }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
private SelectableItemClass _SelectedSItem;
public SelectableItemClass SelectedSItem
{
    get { return _SelectedSItem; }
    set
    {
        if (previewItem == null)
            previewItem = new PreviewItemClass();

        previewItem.descr1 = "aaa";
        previewItem.descr2 = "bbb";
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSItem");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding}" Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext.previewItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}">
    <StackPanel.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Tag.descr1}" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Tag.descr2}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </StackPanel.ToolTip>
    <CheckBox Name="aaaa" Content="{Binding SI_itemName}" IsChecked="{Binding SI_selected}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `ToolTip` is not part of the visual tree.  Thats why you have to set the `DataContext` like this.

```
<ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

If you only want to show a text you can use this as well.

```
<ToolTip Content="{Binding testBind}" />
```

**Edit**

Your problem is you want to bind a property of your parent and not of the selected item. You have to do it like this

```
<ToolTip Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.testBind}" />
```

Comment: I'm not able to find a way to set the datacontext correctly, but I've tested the tooltip on a textbox for example outside the listview and everything works. Why?`<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding testBind}" Width="120" Margin="4,0">
                    <TextBox.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip  Content="{Binding testBind}"/>
                    </TextBox.ToolTip>
                </TextBox>`

Comment: I just see that `testBind` isn't a property of `SelectableItemClass`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, testBind is a string of the viewmodel

Comment: I tried binding the DataContext of the tooltip like this `<ToolTip DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">`. I'm sure I solved this problem in the past more than once, I just can't get it working

Comment: The above suggestion unfortunatelly doesn't work. I've used The Mighty Badaboom code (you can see it in edit part of the topic) on a label above the checkbox named `aaaa`, relativesource seem to works for the label but not for the tooltip

Comment: I've found a similar problem, using the tag I'm able to get the tooltip but unfortunatelly this hack works only for text, I really would like to avoid this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083969/wpf-binding-to-tooltip/4084121)